# Como puedo resolver con tipos de modulos en Java

Tags: java

Como puedo resolver el problema que tengo cuando utilizo los modulos en Java.

Codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unidades { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Declaracion de variable
      int division,
      modulos;

      // Regoledar los datos del usuarios
      System.out.print("Entre un numero entero: ");
      division = input.nextInt();

      // Caculo de los millares
      modulos = division / 1000;
      division = division % 1000;
      System.out.print(modulos + " millares\t");

      // Caluclo de las centenas
      modulos = division / 100;
      division = modulos % 100; 
      System.out.print(modulos + " centenas\t");

      // Calculo de las decenas
      modulos = division / 10;
      division = division % 10;
      System.out.print(modulos + " decenas\t");

      // Calculos de las unidades
      modulos = division / 1;
      division = modulos % 1;
      System.out.print(modulos + " unidades\t");

   }
}
```

Comment: Y bien, ¿cuál es el problema a resolver? ¿qué error sale?

Comment: debes declarar el tipo de variable en el bloque de declaraciones. `int modulos;`

Comment: Bueno de comento, el error que me sale es lo siguiente. El programa compila y funciona pero a la hora de entrar los datos, por ejemplo. Cuando escribo, 3456. La salida que tiene es la siguiente, 3 millares, 4 centenas, 0 decenas y 0 unidades. 

Que lo que espero del programa es lo siguiente, que diga. 3 millares, 4 centenas, 5 decenas y 6 unidades. Lo intentado de diferente forma y me sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes unos pequeños errores en el código, específicamente en el cálculo de las centenas y las unidades:

```
// Caluclo de las centenas
modulos = division / 100;
division = division % 100; // <---- Aquí estabas diviendo la variable modulos
System.out.print(modulos + " centenas\t");

// Calculos de las unidades
modulos = division / 1;
division = division % 1; // <---- Aquí también estabas diviendo la variable modulos
System.out.print(modulos + " unidades\t");
```

Comment: ahh vale, entiendo. por eso no me taba los resultados que esperaba, Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada. Si consideras que la respuesta solucionó tu problema, debes marcarla como respuesta aceptada.

Comment: vale. Lo hare me a sido de ayuda.